# Why does \raggedright not work inside a minipage in this case?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, parbox

In trying to suppress underfull box warnings in annotations to equations in `align` environments, I'm experimenting with `\raggedright`. I've discovered that it works inside a `\parbox` but not inside a `minipage` environment. Why is that?

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\reason}[1]{&&\begin{minipage}{3cm}{\raggedright\small{#1}}\end{minipage}}
\newcommand*{\thereason}[1]{&&\parbox[c]{3cm}{\raggedright\small{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
    a &= b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l   \\
      &\quad + m + n + o + o + q + r + s + t + u + v \\
      &\quad + w + x + y + z 
  \end{split} \reason{a really stupidly long equation split over multiple lines} \\
  \begin{split}
    a &= b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l   \\
      &\quad + m + n + o + o + q + r + s + t + u + v \\
      &\quad + w + x + y + z 
  \end{split} \thereason{a really stupidly long equation split over multiple lines} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\raggedright` does work in minipages as well as in `\parbox`. What matters is the state at the end of the parargaph. In your minipage test, you have extra braces that delimit the raggedright effect before the paragraph is ended.

```
\begin{minipage}{3cm}{\raggedright\small{#1}}\end{minipage}
```

should be

```
\begin{minipage}{3cm}\raggedright\small{#1}\end{minipage}
```

though you could do

```
\begin{minipage}{3cm}{\raggedright\small{#1}\par}\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping it was something simple, and it was.