# How to align qrcode to the right of the page without tables?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, qrcode

In the following example I am using `\raggedleft` which is supposed to align the text to the right. However it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\def\commit{abcdef}
\def\commiturl{https://acme.org/}
\begin{document}
{
  \raggedleft\commit\quad\qrcode{\commiturl}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is my mistake?

Comment: you finished `\raggedleft` with `}` before it was used (this is unrelated to qrcode) leave a blank line before `}` (or use `\begin{flushleft}..\end{flushleft}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Side question: why people on this site prefer to add a comment rather than post an answer?

Comment: because it's probably a duplicate but making a comment gives you help quicker than finding the necessary link to close

Comment: actually related to this but not really a dup so Ill answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570223/why-does-raggedright-not-work-inside-a-minipage-in-this-case/570225?r=SearchResults&s=58|0.0000#570225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paragraph is set according to the settings in scope at the *end* of the paragraph.

You have finished the scope of `\raggedright` at `}` without ending the paragraph so it has no effect other than setting `\parindent` to 0pt as the indent is consulted at the start.

Leave a blank line before `}` (or use `\begin{flushleft}..\end{flushleft}` (note this is unrelated to the qrcode).